# Property of epsilon-subdifferential

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient

For convex function $f$, its subdifferential at $x \in R^n$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\partial f(x) = \{m \mid f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle m,y-x\rangle, \forall y \in R^n\}.
\end{equation}
Then if $f = f_1 + f_2$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both convex, we have
\begin{equation}
\partial f(x)  = \partial f_1(x) + \partial f_2(x).
\end{equation}
This notion can be generalized to $\epsilon$-subdifferential which is defined as
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\epsilon}f(x) = \{m\mid f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle m,y-x\rangle - \epsilon, \forall y \in R^n\},
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon > 0$.

I find a relationship between $\partial_{\epsilon}f(x)$, $\partial_{\epsilon}f_1(x)$ and $\partial_{\epsilon}f_2(x)$ in a paper but without proof, which is
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\epsilon}f(x) \subseteq \partial_{\epsilon}f_1(x) + \partial_{\epsilon}f_2(x)
\end{equation}
I don't know how to prove it. Any hints or references?

Comment: Can the $\epsilon$ subdifferential be characterised in terms of the generalised directional derivative or similar?

Comment: @copper.hat For subdifferential, it can be characterized in terms of the generalized directional derivative. If I remember correctly, it can be found on `Convex Analysis` by Rockafellar. But for $\epsilon$-subdifferential, I am not sure. The relative references are very rare.